# How do I get an event to fire when the slide changes in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I already know of two supposed fixes, which I will list below, along with the reason they don't work for me.

The first is to use the `SlideShowNextSlide` subroutine. The problem with this is that it fires the event before the transition, so I have no way of knowing which slide is being transitioned to. I want the event to fire upon entering certain slides during a presentation, not leaving certain slides. I can't simply add one to the `CurrentShowPosition` field because I'm not necessarily advancing to the next slide; I might click a hyperlink. In short, I want to only fire the events upon *some* transitions from the current slide, but with `SlideShowNextSlide` I have no way of knowing if I am moving to the right slide to fire the event.

The second is to use the `OnSlideShowPageChange` subroutine. The problem with this is that, since I have already saved, closed and reopened my PowerPoint slide show once, PowerPoint simply decides to ignore the code in the subroutine.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I can do? Maybe a way to fix one of the aforementioned problems? I'm using PowerPoint 2013 on Windows 8.1.

Here's the code I want to use:

```
Private Sub EventHandler_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
' The purpose here is to stop music playing in the background, which happens on certain slides.
' For my purposes, it's not enough to simply state how many slides to play the music over,
' because some slides that need the music stopped can occur before slides that need it playing.
Dim Change As Boolean
If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition < 66 And ((SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition < 42 And SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition > 25) Or SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition Mod 2 = 0) _
Then
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("music file.mp3").Delete
    Change = True
End If
If Change Then Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CS As Slide
Set CS = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

If CS.SlideIndex < 66 And CS.SlideIndex > 25 Then
'''
End If
```

I try to verify if I am in the required slide via `SlideIndex` and then run an `If Condition`